# Text color is not updating in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am building an Android application and I need to change the text color of all cells in the ListView.

This is the code I use to populate and connect the ListView with the Activity file:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        // Create a temp array.
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gamesList);
        displayGames = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Populates ListView
        updateList();

        // Create Array Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,displayGames);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

My problem is that the text of the TextView in the cells does not have the correct color even though I specifically changed it on the XML file. See this code below:

This is the XML code for the creation of the ListView:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/gamesList"
        android:layout_width="396dp"
        android:layout_height="342dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.854" />
```

I defined the Text cells in a new XML file called `simple_list_item_1.xml`.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/game"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

I am running the app on a Pixel 2 emulator using API 22 Android 5,1.

Comment: `simple_list_item_1.xml` is your own XML file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While setting Adapter to ListView you are referring `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` which is default system resource and not the one you created in your xml. You need to use `R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

```
// Create Array Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1,displayGames);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` to `R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

```
       // Create Array Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1,displayGames);
```

Comment: duplicated answer. You should edit the first if you want to improve it.